# How to recreate the MySQL's Workbench EER Diagram to an Angular Application

Tags: library, graphs, angular, table, er-diagram

Hi I'm trying to recreate MySQL Workbench EER Diagram in Angular application.
I am using Angular 7. I need to show the relationship between tables and also in column wise. I've searched and found some npm packages. Some of them are proprietary, some doesn't have features that I need:

1. Create EER diagram with the data coming from the backend.
2. Need to connect the tables with arrow illustrating relationship.
3. To have arrows between each table's column.
4. To have labels on the arrow denoting the relationship percentage.

Is it possible, if possible please suggest some tools and libraries.

I need the layout to be something like this:

[image: Sample Layout]

Comment: I love this question and want to see it answered. So, although I would love to be able to represent my database schema in Angular (Angular Js 1.x for me, if not for you , I would ***not***mention databases. Not in the title, not in the question. People who could answer this might think “I know nothing about databases, so I won’t look at that question”. All that you have here is a diagramming question. You want to connect some boxes with arrows attached to specific parts of those boxes (and possibly to drag them around? Google for Dragula) -->

Comment: --> You can leave your picture, but I recommend just asking for a diagramming solution (***must*** it be Angular, or would you accept a plain JS solution? That might widen your chances of an answer). Finally, as you are new, have you searched existing answers? Welcome aboard and good luck; I really want to see an answer to this great question :-)

Comment: I've been searching for libraries & tools which provides these features. Some libraries are paid which I've said earlier.Trying to figure out alternative solution for this challenge.